# PHP convert string to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am looking to convert the following string to a PHP Array:

```
{ 'Codes': ['01239EEF', '01240EDF'], 'Done' : ['1', '0'] }
```

I am trying to convert this to an Array that looks something like the following:

```
{[Codes] => {[0] => '01239EEF', [1] => '01240EDF'}, [Done] => {[0] => '1', [1] => '0'}}
```

I tried using `json_decode` with Array argument explicitly set to `true`. But it always returns `NULL` for some reason.

Comment: If you are creating json yourself then your json is wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

problem is on json use `"` instead of `'`

```
 { 'Codes': ['01239EEF', '01240EDF'], 'Done' : ['1', '0'] }
```

must be

```
 { "Codes": ["01239EEF", "01240EDF"], "Done" : ["1", "0"] }
```

output with `json_decode`

```
 stdClass Object
(
   [Codes] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01239EEF
        [1] => 01240EDF
    )

    [Done] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: Using `str_replace()`: `$str = "{'Codes': ['01239EEF', '01240EDF'], 'Done' : ['1', '0']}";
$array = json_decode(str_replace("'", '"', $str), true);
print_r($array);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace(',",$string)` and then `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

The name and value must be enclosed in double quotes

single quotes are not valid in `json_decode` function

please change your string like

```
$js_str = '{ "Codes": ["01239EEF", "01240EDF"], "Done" : ["1", "0"] }';
```

and your output will be like

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
   ["Codes"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "01239EEF"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "01240EDF"
  }
  ["Done"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```